# Error when trying to use discord.Server in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I've assigned discord.Server() to the var server, which I later wanted to use to get user's name from a list of user ids but as soon as I try to run it this error comes up:

self.id = guild['id']
KeyError: 'id'

Comment: Might need some more info.  The error indicates that the dictionary 'guild' doesn't have a key of 'id'

Answer (score 0):

You should never create discord models other than `Colour`, `Game` (or `Activity` depending on version), `Embed` or a couple others.

You must use an existing reference to an object instead. To find a specific server, you can use

```
bot.get_server("string id")
```

or if you already have a message from say `on_message(message)`, you can access the server through

```
message.server
```